# Can I insert 2 values into A table join B table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert

I have two tables:

```
vote('id', 'question_id', 'ip_id')
```

and

```
ip('id','ip_addr')
```

I want to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO SELECT `vote`.`question_id`, `ip`.`ip_addr` 
            FROM `vote` 
            LEFT JOIN `ip` 
            ON `vote`.`ip_id` = `ip`.`id` VALUES '2','127.0.0.1'
```

the above code is not working, any idea?

Comment: on what table do you want to insert?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `INSERT INTO SELECT` is like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
(Column1, Column3)
SELECT Column1, Column3
FROM Table1
```

So your query should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO <TableName> (`question_id`, `ip_addr`)
            SELECT `vote`.`question_id`, `ip`.`ip_addr` 
            FROM `vote` 
            LEFT JOIN `ip` 
            ON `vote`.`ip_id` = `ip`.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert rows into an existing table using one of the following methods:

```
INSERT INTO vote (id, question_id, ip_id)
VALUES (....)
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO vote (id, question_id, ip_id)
SELECT id, question_id, ip_id 
FROM
    <some existing tables, optionally using joins, where clauses etc., to select the data to insert>
```

In your case, you seem to be trying to insert record in to the `IP` table as well as the `VOTE` table at the same time and that is not possible.

You should first insert a record in the IP table using the first syntax above and then insert into `VOTE` table using the second option.